# How to define an injective and surjective function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I want to show that $|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{N}|$. FWIW, I think again that I must define a injective and surjective function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. But how? Is there any proof as to how could one define such functions and based on what information?

Comment: $\mathbb{N} = \text{odd}+\text{even}$ and $\mathbb{Z}=\text{negative} + \text{positive}$

Comment: "Is there any proof as to how could one define such functions and based on what information?" You made my brain hurt with this sentence...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are to show that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same cardinality, you're correct: you need to find a bijection (hence both injective and surjective) between $\mathbb Z $ and $\mathbb N$

One bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$, defined by:

$$f(k) = 
\begin{cases}  \\ \\ 
2k & \quad k \in \mathbb Z,\; k>0 \\ \\
-2k + 1 & \quad k\in \mathbb Z, \; k \leq 0 \\ \\
\end{cases}
$$

In words, you are simply mapping positive integers to positive even integers, and non-positive integers to positive odd integers.

Comment: You kill the poor problem. + and + for Gigili

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this, $f\colon\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$. By $f(0) = 0,\; f(1) = 1, \;f(-1) = 2,\; f(2) = 3,\; f(-2) = 4,\;$ etc. This gives a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to give an explicit formula for the function $f$.

Comment: Oliver, I simply put your answer (the $f(x)'s$) enclosed in $$ signs. Feel free to roll back to your original post if you are offended by my edit.

Comment: Haha no problem! it looks way better now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach by cases as well:

$\mathbb{N}:0,\ \ \ \ \ 1, \ \ 2,\ \  \ \ \ 3,\ \ 4,\  \ \ \ \  5,\ \ 6,  \ \ \ \ \ 7, \ \ 8,...$

$\mathbb{Z}:0,\  -1, \ 1,\  -2, \ 2, \ -3,\  3,\  -4,\  4,... $

Here you can clearly observe two cases with each with two equations:

Case 1:

- $2x$
- $-2x -1$

Case 2:

- $\frac{x}{2}$
- $-\frac{x+1}{2}$

Solve one case for one-to-one  and the other one for onto function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand how you came up with those two cases.