# Bijection example given set of integers to natural numbers with condition.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

State an example of a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{ 2n \space|\space n\in\mathbb{N} \}$.

I know for a bijection the two sets must have the same cardinality. An example I came up with for this condition is:
$$
f(n)=2n^2, f:\{ ...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,... \}\to\{ 2,4,6,8,... \}
$$

But I'm not sure if this is valid or if I am missing something?

Comment: How do you get $6$ with your function?

Comment: Hint: you don't have to preserve order.

Comment: Oh yeah... How about $f(n)=n^2-n$?

Comment: If $f(n) = n^2 - n$ then $f(3) = f(-2),$ so $f$ is not injective and is therefore not bijective.

Comment: Hint, Nothing says you must use a single algebraic formula.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ohh! So are you suggesting I use an example of a set such as:
$\{ 1,2,3 \}\to\{ 2,4,6 \}$

Comment: @S.B.7 No. $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers, positive and negative. $\mathbb{Z} =$ {$...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...$}. Have a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312879/how-to-define-an-injective-and-surjective-function-from-mathbbz-to-mathbb#:~:text=In%20words%2C%20you%20are%20simply,integers%20to%20positive%20odd%20integers.&text=You%20can%20do%20something%20like,bijection%20from%20Z%20to%20N.

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(n) =4(n+1)$ for $n\ge 0$ and $f(n)=-4n-2$ for $n \lt 0$?

Comment: The range should contain even numbers only

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I missed that... Fixed now!

Answer (score -3):

To answer you question about whether your function $f$ is bijective, the anwer is no. In fact, $f(n)=2n^2$ is very well surjective, since $f(\mathbb{Z})\subset \{2,4,6,...\}$. How every, it is not injective, since, for example, $f(2)=f(-2)$ while $2\not=-2$.

Comment: It is not surjective. Can you generate $6$?

Comment: "*is surjective, since $f(\Bbb Z)\subset \{2,4,6,\dots\}$...*"  That is not the meaning of being surjective here.  That is just being well-defined.  Surjective here would have meant that $f(\Bbb Z)$ is *exactly equal to* $\{2,4,6,\dots\}$, not just merely being a subset of.